# Interactive Grid selection changed event is not firing

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I created a dynamic action to capture selection changed event for an interactive grid.

On True I set Action to "Execute JavaScript" and put in one line

```
console.log(this);
```

When I make a selection nothing is printed out to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried here and works, do you did something diferent that this:

[image]

[image]

Example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:8

The dynamic action is showed together with your IG region?

[image]

Comment: mine is identical to yours

Comment: Are you selecting with your mouse? or programaticaly? This is strange... look like a bug.

Comment: I created the same grid in my test app and it works... I do not understand why it is not working in this one

Comment: The dynamic action is showed together with your IG region?

Comment: found it! I had a javascript error in Page_Load dynamic action. As soon as I fixed it, everything else worked